# Python "graphics.py" library working, but there is no method .yUp()

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I've imported the graphics library and everything works without a hitch. Except the supposed .yUp() method that is supposed to orient the drawing grid correctly.

Has this method been removed since the documentation for this came out?

This is the example I was working with (from http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html)

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Face', 200, 150) # give title and dimensions
    win.yUp() # make right side up coordinates!

    head = Circle(Point(40,100), 25) # set center and radius
    head.setFill("yellow")
    head.draw(win)

    eye1 = Circle(Point(30, 105), 5)
    eye1.setFill('blue')
    eye1.draw(win)

    eye2 = Line(Point(45, 105), Point(55, 105)) # set endpoints
    eye2.setWidth(3)
    eye2.draw(win)

    mouth = Oval(Point(30, 90), Point(50, 85)) # set corners of bounding box
    mouth.setFill("red")
    mouth.draw(win)

    label = Text(Point(100, 120), 'A face')
    label.draw(win)

    message = Text(Point(win.getWidth()/2, 20), 'Click anywhere to quit.')
    message.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
main()
```

Can anybody figure out why win.yUp() seems to not exist anymore?

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting?

Comment: AttributeError: 'GraphWin' object has no attribute 'yUp'

Comment: `yUp` does not exist in [Zelle's version of graphics](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py). Are you sure you have the right `graphics` module?

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Andrew N. Harrington (anh) uses his own variant of John Zelle's graphics library split off from Zelle's version 4.2 5/26/2011 -- Zelle's current version is 5 8/26/2016 or later.

Harrington's variant adds: `promptMouse`, `promptClose`, and `yUp'.  You can find it [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/examples.zip)

You should be able to just copy the `yUp()` function from Harrington's source into your own file since it's just a call to Zelle's `setCoords()` function with specific constants to adjust the window.